# Perl Regular Expressions: Question mark isn't greedily matching

Tags: regex, perl

```
$var = 'about/';
$var =~ s/^(.*)\/?$/index.php?action=$1/;
```

I want it to match and substitute the trailing slash.  But it isn't, I'm getting this result:

```
index.php?action=about/
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried wrapping it in parenthesis `(\/)?` and including the question mark in the parenthesis `(\/?)`.  Not including the preceding forward slash obviously doesn't do me any good.  So how can I get it to eat the slash when it's there?

Comment: You may find your code more readable if you pick a different delimiter for regexs containing slashes.  I usually use `!`, because it's not commonly used in regexs.  e.g. `s!^(.*)/?$!index.php?action=$1!`

Comment: Could you post your desired output? Thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is, that the `.*` is greedy as well. Try using `.*?`.

The Regex engine is first expanding `.*` as far as possible, then checks if the regex can match the input. In your case, it does, since the trailing slash is optional. It then goes home satisfied.

Comment: Oh, of course.  *sigh* RegEx's have always given me trouble, because there's always something like that that manages to bite me in the butt.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make `.*` ungreedy :

```
$var = 'about/';
$var =~ s!^(.*?)/?$!index.php?action=$1!;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your substitution, you're trying really hard to specify what you keep. It's much easier in this case to get rid of what you don't want. When a feature seems hard to use for your application, that's a sign that you're using the wrong feature.

It looks like you want to do is remove the last / in a string. So, just remove the last /:

```
 my $path = 'about/';
 $path = s|/\z||;

 my $action = "index.php?action=$path";
```

If you really wanted to do this in-place (a dubious goal), you could just do this:

```
 ( my $action = "index.php?action=$path" ) =~ s|/\z||;
```

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to do.  This is a regex that is eventually going to find its way into a MOD_REWRITE RewriteRule.  And this is only part of the final result.  I'm just testing it in bits an pieces in Perl and putting it together so that I know it'll do what I want when I finally put it into an htaccess file.

Comment: That would have been good information to include in your question. It's always a little sad when I find out I've wasted my time because the questioner left out really important information like that.